# Merge utilizando o Hibernate sem apagar outros dados Java

Tags: java, hibernate, merge

Utilizo na minha aplicação Java o Hibernate para interação com banco utilizo uma classe controladora criada mesmo pelo NetBeans, só que o problema que tenho é o seguinte, ao realizar uma edição em algum campo e só passar este valor no método que vou chamar e fazer merge todos os outros que não passei são setados como nulo alimentando somente o campo que passei informação.

Segue abaixo o método da classe controladora que faz a atualização de dados.

ProdutoDAO.java

```
 public void edit(Produto produto) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        produto = em.merge(produto);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Integer id = produto.getCodproduto();
            if (findProduto(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The produto with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clayton, para melhor lhe ajudar, seria necessário que a classe Produto e a atualização do mesmo estivesse no corpo da pergunta, caso ainda não tenha resolvido, adiciona ai que teremos prazer em lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metodo refresh do EntityManager atualiza a instância do banco de dados, sobrescrevendo as propriedades especificadas e mantendo as outras.

A entidade que deve ser passada deve estar no estado administrado(managed).

Infelizmente o metodo refresh não funciona em gerenciadores de contêiner como Spring e EJB.

Resumindo, o metodo refresh funciona como merge para as propriedades especificadas.

**Por Exemplo:**

```
Produto p = em.find(Produto.class, 1);  
em.refresh(p);

// Depois do commit o objeto sera salvo no banco de dados
p.setNome("TV Full HD");
```

No seu caso vai ficar algo como isto:

```
public void edit(Produto p) {
    EntityManager em = null;

    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Produto produto = em.find(Produto.class, p.getId());
        em.refresh(produto);

        if(p.getNome() != null) {
            produto.setNome(p.getNome());
        }

        // Outras propriedades que você queira sobrescrever

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Integer id = produto.getCodproduto();
            if (findProduto(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The produto with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pode detalhar melhor no exemplo que propus acima? Obrigado.

Comment: Ok, pelo que entendi, no caso terei que fazer produto.set para cada campo meu que existe no banco de dados?

Comment: É os gets e sets são da sua entidade de jpa produto

Comment: Marca como a resposta correta

Answer (score 0):

Se caso ainda não tenha resolvido, verifique as configurações do seu persistence.xml.

Veja se contem essa propriedade: name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"

Se preferir utilize uma ferramente que desenvolvi que facilita muito o trabalho com hibernate.

link: https://github.com/KaynanCoelho/generic-repository

Até.